# How to find the Laurent series for $\frac{1}{(z-1)(z-2)}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, laurent-series

How to find the Laurent series for $$\frac{1}{(z-1)(z-2)}$$ on $|z|<2$

Here is what I did so far:

$$\frac{1}{(z-1)(z-2)}=\frac{1}{(z-2)}-\frac{1}{(z-1)}$$ now $$\frac{1}{(z-1)}=\frac{-1}{(1-z)}=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n$$ as long as $|z|<1$ which is where we are looking for the series so this is fine.

Now to deal with the second part is where I cannot figure out how to proceed $$\frac{1}{(z-2)}=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^n$$ but this is only valid on $|z|<2$ but this is not what is needed.

Alternatively we can factor out $z$ to get $$\frac{1}{(z-2)}=\frac{1}{z}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2}{z}\right)^n$$ which is valid for $|2/z|<1 \implies |z|>2$ again this is not what we want.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If $|z|<1$, then $|z|<2$.

Comment: Wow. Honestly I feel so dumb right now. It follows automatically then that it will hold on $|z|<1$. Guess that's what I get for doing 12 hours math in one day. One more question how do we know whether to factor out the number (in this case 2) or the z? Is it just see what works or is there a way to determine what to factor.

Comment: You only need to get something of the form $1/(1-w)$ with $|w|<1$, and that determines whatever should be done.

Comment: Okay thanks that makes sense.